# Add Total Column to one single line and calculate and don't display duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I Have the output displayed right now like below displayed, But i need that Bill Total charges column to be added if there is same Physician name and same def code.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

From your data, simple aggregation with the `SUM` function should suffice, e.g.:

```
select
    AccountNumber,
    IDnumber,
    DischargeDate,
    OutStandingDays,
    DefCode,
    Name,
    SUM(BillTotalCharges) as Charges,
    DeficiencyPhysician
from
    table1
group by
    AccountNumber,
    IDnumber,
    DischargeDate,
    OutStandingDays,
    DefCode,
    Name,
    DeficiencyPhysician
```

Comment: the above query didnt help. should i post you my query

Comment: @kreme123 you should **always** post your query

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps for just one `sum` of `BillTotalCharges` you need to have a lot of columns in `group by` to have a sync with `sum`

```
       Select AccountNumber, IDnumber, DischargeDate, 
        OutStandingDays, DefCode, Name,           
        sum(BillTotalCharges), DeficiencyPhysician from 
         table 
        group by 
        AccountNumber, IDnumber, DischargeDate, 
        OutStandingDays, DefCode, Name,           
        DeficiencyPhysician
```

Comment: The above line didnt help me , should i post my query.

Comment: check it again with the above query

Comment: now it says the below error AccountNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: i guess u mistyped it it maybe a typo check again your query it should work as you can see accountno is there in group by you migh have added `'` after AccountNumber check this typo

Comment: can i have the emailid please , so that i can share or give me message to alukuri.infa at gmail dot com